# How to release a ValueTask that wraps a side-effect without using await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, valuetask, ivaluetasksource

If I have a "resultless" [`ValueTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask), (as in plain `ValueTask`, not a [`ValueTask<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1)) that has completed synchronously such that `valueTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully` is true. The `ValueTask` has not been `await`ed. How do I tell to the runtime that I'm done with the `ValueTask`, and that it can be reused if it happens to be backed by a `IValueTaskSource`?

`ValueTask<T>` has a `Result` property and accessing it (presumably) marks the `ValueTask<T>` as consumed, but a plain `ValueTask` has no `Result`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can notify the underlying [`IValueTaskSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.sources.ivaluetasksource) object that the [`ValueTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask) has been consumed, by calling the [`.GetAwaiter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask.getawaiter)[`.GetResult()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.valuetaskawaiter.getresult) method on the task:

```
if (valueTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
{
    valueTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

This call does not cause any allocation. The [`ValueTaskAwaiter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.valuetaskawaiter) is a struct.

The effect that the `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` has on consuming the `ValueTask` is not documented. It can only be derived by studying the source code of the relevant types ([`ValueTask`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v7.0.0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs), [`ValueTaskAwaiter`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v7.0.0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/ValueTaskAwaiter.cs), [`ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v7.0.0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Sources/ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore.cs)).

**Caution:** Calling the `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` before the task is completed, is not a valid operation for a `ValueTask`. It is also forbidden to call the `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` more than once, or in tandem with any other consuming operation like `await` or [`AsTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask.astask). These restrictions are documented in the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask#remarks) section of the `ValueTask` struct.

Comment: `GetAwaiter()` "Creates an awaiter for this value", as per documentation. Is that necessary if we already know that it completed successfully? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of the ValueTask?

Comment: I just spent the last 3 hours going through the sources and indeed you're correct. The internal method `ValueTask.ThrowIfCompletedUnsuccessfully`, which is what I need, is only exposed in 2 places: the compiler-generated awaiter and  the`ValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()` (which just delegates to the internal `ValueTask.ThrowIfCompletedUnsuccessfully`). The `ValueTask<T>` however has the same code directly in the `Result` getter without going through the awaiter. Both are calling `IValueTaskSource.GetResult()`, which is what's _actually_ responsible for "consuming" the task's token.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just `await` it?

Comment: @Charlieface Because the method where I need this isn't `async`. I had to change the implementation of an existing method and realized that the `ValueTask` doesn't have the equivalent of `ValueTask<T>.Result` and wondered how to signal to the eventual `IValueTaskSource` that the task was consumed, hence my question.